# How can I correctly say in a pseudocode to stop the iteration of the while loop but not finishing the while loop itself?

Tags: pseudocode

In many programming languages it's "continue"... However the word can be misinterpreted by people not used to coding...
How can I say it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

I think that using other words will just made thing less clear. So I would suggest to explain"break" which is very easy to understand before explaining "continue"

Comment: You mean something like: "Break Iteration" or "Stop Iteration"?

Comment: `break` means something different from `continue` in most C-like languages

Answer (score 0):

You can say "skip to next iteration" or "continue with next iteration", or perhaps "skip to processing next item/point/integer/etc", if your audience is not familiar with the word "iteration" as used in computing. It's more verbose than "continue" but there should be more than enough space fi you write it on its own line.